# How to make a page break when there is not enough space?

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation

I am trying to generate a product stock report in PDF. To do this, I first created the report in HTML.

Firstly I created the table with the list of products and at the end of this, a small table with the taxable base, the VAT and the total of selected products.

The problem is, that table is divided if there are too many lines in the list. For example, you can leave the tax base and the VAT on the first page and since the total does not fit anymore, you can move it to the next one.

What I need is that this small table should be inseparable and that if it does not fit in one page because the list is very long,it should jump to the next one.

I tried using page-break-before property but it does not work at all.

Any recommendations on how I can do it?

Thank you!

[image: report]

Comment: Normally applying: `page-break-inside: avoid` to the element should fix your problem. However, without a [mcve] it is impossible to know for sure. Also note `page-break-before` has been replaced with [`break-before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put `<div> ... </div>` as a page break.

If not  in the css file : the `div` : display: block

Comment: Yeah. Is the frist thing i try, but nothing